# javax.EJB cannot resolve import (wildfly)

Tags: java, import, ejb, wildfly, java-ee-7

I am getting the "import javax.ejb cannot be resolved" error. I have Wildfly, and is already running as my server. My project has wildfly as the targeted runtime. I have been reading that when using Glass Fish you just have to add a path to a javaee.jar file. But I don't see such file (or similar) in Wildfly. I don't even see a lib folder. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you use Eclipse? If yes, then you have to create a "Server Runtime". The best/quickest method for that is to install "Jboss Tools" in Eclipse and then create the Wildfly "Server Runtime" and then add it to your EJB project as a dependency. As an alternative you could add the same javaee.jar to your dependency (as External Jar).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that jboss-ejb-api***.jar is in your classpath. Should be in

> [JBOSS_HOME]/modules/javax/ejb/main

Hope that helps